# Handle swipe of PageViewer Programmatically in TabBar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, gesture, tabbar, flutter-pageview

### I have Implemented `TabBar` with 3 Tabs. In 2nd Tab, the class contains `PageViewer` and its 3 Pages.

Now when I swipe from 1st tab to 3rd Tab, the order of page appearing is this:

```
1st Tab >> 
2nd Tab(PageViewer index 0th page) > (index 1st page) > (index 2nd page) >> 
3rd Tab.
```

But when I swipe from 3rd Tab to 1st Tab, the order of page appearing is this:

```
3rd Tab >>
2nd Tab(PageViewer index 0th page) >>
1st Tab.
```

---

What I want when I go from 3rd Tab to 1st Tab is:

```
3rd Tab >>
2nd Tab(PageViewer index 3rd page) > (index 2nd page) > (index 1st page) >>
1st Tab.
```

I am looking for solution that can have Code sample or Handling with gestures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the track of the previous tab index. Use that to render the pageview's initial page. Refer following code sample.

Tabbar included widget,

```
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}
class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  // keeps the track of tab index
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {
      if (_tabController.index != 1) _currentIndex = _tabController.index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
            ],
          ),
          title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            Center(child: Text('Tab 1')),
            SecondTab(tabIndex: _currentIndex),
            Center(child: Text('Tab 3')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Pageview included second tab widget,

```
class SecondTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final int tabIndex; // tab index, which came from
  SecondTab({Key key, @required this.tabIndex}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // set initial page to first or last based on previous tab index
    final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: tabIndex);

    return PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(child: Text('First Page')),
        Center(child: Text('Second Page')),
        Center(child: Text('Third Page')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I hope you can get an idea from this.

Comment: Thank you, Now I can use this logic everywhere in my app. This worked perfectly :)